# Next js Redux, Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: next.js

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Tried to fix this for days and no result.

i have a model

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const CategoriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    parent: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'categories'
    },
   
}, 
{
    timestamps: true
})
let Dataset = mongoose.models.categories || mongoose.model('categories', CategoriesSchema)
export default Dataset
```

and i have getCategories like this
[getCategories ]

```js
const getCategories = async (req, res) => {
  try {
   
    const categories = await Categories.find().populate("parent", "name");
    
    res.json({ categories });
  } 
  catch (err) 
  {
    return res.status(500).json({ err: err.message });
  }
};
```

in my Globale state i have

```js
export const DataContext = createContext()

export const DataProvider = ({children}) => {
    const initialState = { 
        notify: {}, auth: {}, cart: [], modal: [], orders: [], users: [], categories: []
    }
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducers, initialState)
    useEffect(() => {
        getData('categories').then(res => {
            if(res.err) 
            return dispatch({type: 'NOTIFY', payload: {error: res.err}})
    
           dispatch({ type: 'ADD_CATEGORIES', payload: res.categories })
        })
        
    },[])
    return(
        <DataContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
            {children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

when i call categories throw:[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnkw3.png)

when i change dispatch in Globale state like :

```js
 dispatch({ type: 'ADD_CATEGORIES', payload: [] })
```

i get no elements in array :[image]

Comment: Can you show is the code for `getData`? Also, what's the value of `res.categories`? Does the API call return the expected data?